# LyX "exam" document layout - multiple paragraphs per question

Tags: lyx, exam, lyx-layouts

I am using Christopher Fuhrman's exam layout in LyX. When using the SmartQuestion style, I can add a numbered list of questions, but I cannot find a way to include paragraph breaks for multiple paragraphs in a single question. Whenever I try to break the paragraph, I get a new list item with the subsequent number.

Comment: Help us to help you by providing a minimal working example (mwe) that shows your problem

Comment: To confirm, you are referring to this layout? https://github.com/fuhrmanator/lyx-layouts/blob/master/exam/exam.layout (It's not a standard one I believe, so best to include a link to where people can find it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest method is to add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and type `\par` in it. Remeber to add a space after the `\par`, either inside or outside the ERT inset.

An alternative is this rather cumbersome keyboard sequence that I stumbled upon:

1. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

(You can of course add a hard line break with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but that's not a paragraph break, so usually you don't want to do that.)

Here's how those three options look in LyX:

[image]

Comment: The second solution given seems to work the best for me. However, for some reason, the layout is insisting on starting the question at the top of a new page when the question extends past the current page. Subsequent pages break correctly, however.